# How to get contents of a command TCL

Tags: tcl

I want to see the contents of a command.

Please suggest to me how to get the contents of a command (the code which maps to the respective command)?

```
blah::do_something
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaningful body for a general command. For example, the `lset` command has several different implementations over several C functions; there's the interpreted version, plus several versions for handling bytecode-compiled versions, plus the function that compiles the source to the bytecode. Many Tcl commands have this sort of internal complexity, but they behave the same whichever implementation strategy is actually used. What's more, there's no attempt to provide a map into the space of command implementations that is visible from Tcl code; you'll have to just search the Tcl source code for the version that you are interested in.

Procedures are different, a special subclass of command; there we *explicitly* keep the source code around so that it can be retrieved with `info body`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `info body` command to get the contents of a procedure.

```
% proc add {a b} {
        return [expr {$a+$b}]
}
% info body add

        return [expr {$a+$b}]

%
```

Comment: I see that this works for only procedures. Could you please suggest any other way? , I want to see the contents of the commands listed when we use info procs

Comment: We can extract only if it is written via `proc`. Internal commands such as `lindex` (or whatsoever) it won't work, since they are developed in C to support a specific purpose. This also helps in hiding the behind the scene stuffs. STC's HLT API is one such example.

Comment: Thanks for the Info, I am using a tool which is built on tcl. I see that there are many commands which aren't inbuilt . So can we the stuff in this case?

Comment: If you get an error message as `"cmd" isn't a procedure` for any `cmd`, then it is a inbuilt command, then you can't fiddle into it.